# Bean Validation Messages from the Program

Tags: java, field, message, bean-validation

I have a bean with validation annotations. I am going to trigger the validation manually using the following code:

```
 Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
 Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(object, validationGroup);
```

My question is, 1.) how do you get the field that failed validation and 2.) How to get the associated message?

I do not want to use .properties file. There is no front-end to display. But its a service and I need to send response with failed validation message and field that failed validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **How do you get the field that failed validation?**

The field that failed validation will be returned in the `MethodConstraintViolationException`.  You retrieve the individual violations by calling `getConstraintViolations()` and then the field can be retrieved by `getPropertyPath()` and walking the nodes.

However, if you have a case where the field name returned in the response does not match the name of the property in the bean, for example if you are returning snake case responses (i.e. `user_name`), but your bean property name is `username`, you have to get a little more creative.

In this scenario you can store the name of the field as a `Payload` on the bean validation annotation.

**Response Field:**

```
@JsonProperty("user_name")
@NotEmpty(message = ErrorMessageKeys.USERNAME_REQUIRED, 
          payload = {FieldNamePayload.UserName.class})
private String username;
```

**Payload Class:**

```
public class FieldNamePayload 
{
    /**
     * Represents the field name "user_name"
     */
    public static class UserName implements ValuePayload
    {
        private static final String value = "user_name";

        @Override
        public String getValue() 
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Retrieving the Payload in your Exception Mapper:**

```
    List<MethodConstraintViolation<?>> violations = new ArrayList<MethodConstraintViolation<?>>(exception.getConstraintViolations());

    for(MethodConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations)
    {
        String field = getFieldName(violation);
        String message = violation.getMessage();

        for(Class<? extends Payload> payload : new ArrayList<Class<? extends Payload>>(violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getPayload()))
        {
            //Retrieve field name from constraint payload
            if(payload.isAssignableFrom(FieldNamePayload.UserName.class))
            {
                field = getPayloadValue(payload);
            }
        }

        //Create an error response here!
    }
```

---

> **How do you get the associated message?**

By default the bean validation framework looks up the messages in localized files at the root of the classpath with the following naming convention:

- `ValidationMessages.properties` for the default locale.
- `ValidationMessages_{locale}.properties` when localization is required

If you want to override this behavior and change where the validation messages are being retrieved from you can use hibernate's validation provider and implement a custom `ResourceBundleLocator` which you would add to the `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator`.

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation
    .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
    .configure()
    .messageInterpolator(
        new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
            new MyCustomResourceBundleLocator()))
    .buildValidatorFactory();
```

Comment: If I do not want to Override the messages, and I just want to get the default validation message?

Comment: The default messages are on the MessageConstraintViolation object.  Call the getMessage() method.  Take a look at the exception mapper code above.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1, what do you mean with field? The java.lang.reflect.Field? You don't get access to it directly. What you can do is to call ConstraintViolation#getPropertyPath to get the property path. You need to iterate the nodes and at the leaf node you can call for example getName() to get the property name and getKind() to determine the type of the node.

Regarding 2, ConstraintViolation#getMessage() gives you the interpolated error message

I am not sure what you mean when you say that you don't want to use a properties file. Bean Validation will per default read the error messages from properties files (either the built-in ones, or the ones you add to your application).

Comment: 1.) Field means, bean variable/property. Not "Field". If I specified @NotNull, and if that variable failed this constraint, I need to be able to get the message 2.)Googling about error messages returned me samples using properties files for Bean validation error messages. However, I do not intend to use it.